# Finding the route with connecting flights using N1QL

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to extend the sample travel app available in Couchbase to display flights from source to destination with possible routes which includes connecting flight similar to what we generally see when searching expedia or similar travel sites

For Example : Source: Orlando Destination:Dayton. I am trying to display the following
1. Direct flights from Oralando to Dayton
2. Flights with one connection ( Orlando -> New York, New York -> Dayton)
3. other flights with more than one connecting flight.

Is there a way we can achieve this using N1QL?

Note: Using the travel sample data available in the couchbase installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do such queries for arbitary-length paths. This is a well-known problem in standard SQL that N1QL shares. There are a few types of SQL that permit recursive queries, and they can solve this problem, but N1QL isn't one of them.

The best that N1QL can offer is (a query for direct flights UNION ALL a query for paths of length 2 UNION ALL a query for paths of length 3 UNION ALL ...), but then you need to know the maximum path length you will accept.

The queries for paths of length 2 or more would be written using JOINs.

You'll also need to avoid odd things such as redundant legs, as in this path:
Toronto -> New York -> Atlanta -> New York -> Miami

I suggest you implement the search for these multi-step flights in the app server using something like breadth-first search, and use N1QL to retrieve eligible flights at each step.